The gacha stamp collector’s problem
Let $N \gg n \geq 2$ be fixed natural numbers. In the Gacha stamp game, players are given an $N \times N$ square grid, with each point occupied by a unique stamp.
On every turn, they may choose a subsquare of size $n \times n$, and they are given uniformly at random a copy of one of the stamps from the subsquare.
Question: Under a strategy that is optimal for minimising the expected time taken, what is the expected time taken to get one of each stamp?
As detailed in the comments, the simple non-optimal strategy of filling in each subsquare before moving on gives expected time $\sim N^2 \log n$. The exact result is actually $N^2 H_{n^2}$.
In any case, it is clear one cannot get better than $\Theta_n (N^2)$ with any strategy.
So the natural next question is whether one can improve the $\log n$ factor. Failing that, one can ask for precise constants, which I think is also interesting.

Is the strategy open loop?

Sure, if you want, though if probably only depends on the collection of stamps you currently have, counted without multiplicity. So you could get a Markov strategy. @user479223

Here's a non-optimal strategy. Choose $n=2$, and fill up each subsquare before proceeding to a disjoint subsquare. The expected time is $N^2 H_4 = \frac{25}{12} N^2$. In general, it feels somewhat tempting that $n$ small is the way to go, but I'm not sure. At the least, it's clear that the best strategy has cost $\Theta(N^2)$.

@user196574 Oh i guess it may not have been clear - $n$ is fixed by the game host.

@user196574 I agree with the $\Theta(N^2)$, now the interesting part is the coefficient of this $N^2$ in $n$…

@NateRiver Thanks, that makes sense! Then one has at least $N^2 H_n$ as a non-optimal strategy, so the best strategy is no worse than $\sim N^2 \log(n)$. I'm curious if you can get better than $\log(n)$.

I think better than $\log(n)$ may be impossible - consider that in any strategy there will be quite many (not sure exactly the quantity) choices of squares that are mostly already filled up.

Also, you have $N^2 H_{n^2}$ instead, slight typo xD. But this is still of course $\sim N^2 \log (n)$.

It probably doesn't matter terribly (I'd expect just a subleading term), but would you prefer open boundary conditions or periodic ones?

Could you elaborate on what is meant by open and periodic? @user196574

Roughly, can I identify opposite edges of the $N \times N$ square so that I can e.g. place the $n \times n$ square so that it crosses the left boundary and pops out on the right boundary? That way no $n \times n$ squares are distinguished at the very first step by their closeness to the boundary, since there is no boundary and instead there's a translation symmetry.

Ah yes, I figured something like that. I think I like the original “open boundary conditions” better, but of course near variants of the problem are equally interesting, and this one with periodicity seems more tractable. @user196574

For the simple non-optimal strategy, I was imagining that a covering made of $n \times n$ subsquares would be filled one-by-one. The expected time of filling a given subsquare goes as $n^2 H_{n^2}$, while there are $(N/n)^2$ such subsquares. Then the cost would go as $(N/n)^2 n^2 H_{n^2} = N^2 H_{n^2} \sim 2 N^2 \log(n)$. Where did the extra $1/n$ come from?

Ah, not careful enough. I had for some reason $n H_{n}$ instead of $n^2 H_{n^2}$ for filling the square. Will modify appropriately. @user196574

One can improve the $\log n$ factor by at most a constant.
Divide the $N \times N$ board into $n\times n $ squares. (Even if $n$ is not a divisor of $N$, one can divide at most a quarter of the board in this way). Call these the fixed squares.
Each $n \times n$ move intersects each of the fixed squares. The progress we make from the $n\times n$ move is at most the progress we make if we could make four simultaneous moves in the four fixed squares it intersects, with the stamps in the four subsquares we obtain possibly correlated.
But this version of the problem takes time at least $N^2 H_{n^2}/4$.

Elegant as always…
